# ChartJS incorrect plot when plotting multiple line charts in one graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I am trying to plot multiple line charts on a graph and I have a toggle to disable / enabled some of the plots. I am destroying / updating whenever required but when I see a particular plot separately, I can see a different plot but when its a mixed graph, the line shows a different plot.

Example fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/njmr15w9/ ( You can try to comment first two plots from the dataset array and you can see how the green plot changes and shows incorrect points, which should not be the case )

```
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8],
    datasets: [
      {
          label: "Set 1",
          data: [10, 20, null, 40, 30,null,20,40],
          borderColor: "#F00",
          fill: false,
          steppedLine: false,
          tension: 0,
          fillBetweenSet: 1,
          fillBetweenColor: "rgba(255,0,0, 0.2)"
      },
      {
          label: "Set 2",
          data: [60, 40, 10, 50, 60,null,50,20],
          borderColor: "#00F",
          fill: false,
          steppedLine: false,
          tension: 0.5
      },
      {
          label: "Set 2",
          data: [40, 50, 30, 30, 20,null,60,40],
          borderColor: "#0D0",
          fill: false,
          steppedLine: false,
          tension: 0,
          fillBetweenSet: 1,
          fillBetweenColor: "rgba(5,5,255, 0.2)"
      }
    ]
};

var chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Demo Fill between lines'
    }
};

var chartDemo = new Chart($('#demo').get(0), {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed your instructions and commented out the first two datasets. The result looks fine to me.

```js
const chartData = {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  datasets: [
    /*
    {
      label: "Set 1",
      data: [10, 20, null, 40, 30, null, 20, 40],
      borderColor: "#F00",
      fill: false,
      steppedLine: false,
      tension: 0,
      fillBetweenSet: 1,
      fillBetweenColor: "rgba(255,0,0, 0.2)"
    },
    {
      label: "Set 2",
      data: [60, 40, 10, 50, 60, null, 50, 20],
      borderColor: "#00F",
      fill: false,
      steppedLine: false,
      tension: 0.5
    },
    */
    {
      label: "Set 2",
      data: [40, 50, 30, 30, 20, null, 60, 40],
      borderColor: "#0D0",
      fill: false,
      steppedLine: false,
      tension: 0,
      fillBetweenSet: 1,
      fillBetweenColor: "rgba(5,5,255, 0.2)"
    }
  ]
};

var chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Demo Fill between lines'
  }
};

var chartDemo = new Chart(document.getElementById('demo'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="demo" height="90"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE**

The problem lies in the `fillBetweenLinesPlugin` that simply doesn't work correctly when only one line is drawn. This can easily be fixed by changing the condition in the `for` loop by adding `datasets.length > 1` as follows.

```
for (var d = 0; datasets.length > 1 && d < datasets.length; d++) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's weird. If you see the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/njmr15w9/), I am still able to reproduce the error there.